# Adobe Air with Javascript, making a program wait while running nativeProcess

Tags: javascript, dom-events, air

I'm trying to extract metadata from video files by running `ffprobe` using `nativeProcess`. The code below works just as it should for one file, but causes an error when trying to loop through a series of files.

I know the cause of the problem is that Air tries to start a new `nativeProcess` before the old one is finished. I know it's something to do with listening to the `air.NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT`. I just can't get it to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
function fileOpen(){
    
  var directory = air.File.userDirectory;
  
  try
  {
      directory.browseForDirectory("Select Directory");
      directory.addEventListener(air.Event.SELECT, directorySelected);
  }
  catch (error)
  {
      air.trace("Failed:", error.message)
  }
  
  function directorySelected(event) 
  {
      directory = event.target ;
      var files = directory.getDirectoryListing();
      for(i=0; i < files.length; i++){
        getMetadata(files[0].nativePath)
                    //wait here for nativeProcess to finish
        }
      }
  } 

function getMetadata(filePathIn){
    
         
        if(air.NativeProcess.isSupported)
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            air.trace("NativeProcess not supported.");
        }
    
        fileIn = filePathIn.toString()

        var nativeProcessStartupInfo = new air.NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        var file = air.File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("ffprobe");
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

        args = new air.Vector["<String>"]();
        args.push("-sexagesimal","-show_format","-loglevel","quiet","-show_streams","-print_format","json",filePathIn)
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;

        process = new air.NativeProcess();
        process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo); 
        process.addEventListener(air.ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
        process.addEventListener(air.ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
        process.addEventListener(air.NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
        process.addEventListener(air.IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        process.addEventListener(air.IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        
        
    }

    function onOutputData()
    {
      var fileMetadataJSON = process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);
      air.trace(fileMetadataJSON)
    }
    
    function onErrorData(event)
    {
        air.trace("ERROR -", process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable)); 
    }
    
    function onExit(event)
    {
        air.trace("Process exited with ", event.exitCode);
    
    }
    
    function onIOError(event)
    {
         air.trace(event.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an outline that should give you an idea of what to do:

- In your `directorySelected()` method, promote the local variable `files` (an Array) to a member variable. This will make the list of files that was selected available so that other methods can access it.
- Remove the `for` loop in your `directorySelected()` method. Instead of running the loop and trying to run the native process here, call a new method, let's call it `dequeueFileAndRunNativeProcess()`.
- This new `dequeueFileAndRunNativeProcess()` method should check the length of the `files` array, and if it is greater than 0, it should `pop()` the first file in the `files` array and execute the native process on it.
- In your `onExit()` method, call the `dequeueFileAndRunNativeProcess()` method again.

The idea here is to move the code that runs the native process into a method that you can trigger from two places: once immediately after the user finishes browsing for files, and then again after the native process finishes it's work. The process ends when the `files` array has no more files in it.